# How can I get android Honeycomb system's screen width and height?

Tags: android, height, width, screen, android-3.0-honeycomb

my code:

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);

System.out.println("screen width:"+displayMetrics.widthPixels);
System.out.println("screen heigth:"+displayMetrics.heightPixels);
```

when I run this program in android Honeycomb system,the output is
800 and 1232
but the device's screen is 800_1280,hao can I get it?
thanks.

Comment: Looks like it is only telling you the window size - if you set it to be full screen you will probably get the full size

Comment: How are you getting these dimension values? The height of 1232 is actually the screen size minus the navigation bar height (the bar on the bottom with the back, home, etc buttons) (i.e. 1280 - 48 = 1232). So you are getting the usable screen space for your Activity (assuming you have it set to no title bar). The thing is I've tried the same code you did but I get the absolute screen size of 800x1280 returned to me. I would actually like to know how **YOU** got it to return 1232. I tested my code on version 3.1

Answer (score 6):

This piece of code works for me (if you don't mind to use undocumented methods):

```
Display d = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width, height;

Method mGetRawH;
Method mGetRawW;
try {
    mGetRawH = Display.class.getMethod("getRawWidth");
    mGetRawW = Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight");
    width = (Integer) mGetRawW.invoke(d);
    height = (Integer) mGetRawH.invoke(d);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//You should care about orientation here
int o = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    if (width > height) {
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }
} else if (o == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
    if (width < height) {
        int tmp = width;
        width = height;
        height = tmp;
    }
}

Log.d("d", "w=" + width + " h=" + height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually device full screen `width=800 and height=1280` `(including status bar, title bar)`. If you run your code to get display size, the system will not include status bar height and title bar height, so you will get `height as 1232 (1280-(status bar height + title bar height))`.

Answer (score 0):

1280 x 752 - landscape
800 x 1232 - portrait

This 48 px are for the Andriod default notification bar...