# Landscape Window Dimension Android

Tags: android, dimensions

I have been having trouble getting the screen dimensions for android.  I do not want the size of the status bars included in my dimenions.  The app that I'm developing is to be permanently in landscape mode.  I have been testing with the android honeycomb emulator.  When I get the dimensions using the code in [How can I get android Honeycomb system's screen width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144814/how-can-i-get-android-honeycomb-systems-screen-width-and-height) I get 1280x800.  I was curious as to why the person in the linked question has the size of the status bars subtracted while mine does not work that way.  Also, how can I make it so that the size of the status bars is actually subtracted?  If any additional details are needed I will be checking periodically to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay!  I finally figured it out.  I pieced together code from several different sources so I don't know exactly why things work out the way they do.  Here is the relevant code.

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
Window win = getWindow();
win.getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
screenWidth = Math.abs(rect.left-rect.right);
screenHeight = Math.abs(rect.top-rect.bottom);
```

There is one caveat though. This code **WILL NOT** work in the onCreate() method.  Instead, place it in

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus)
```

This should solve any problems with getting window dimensions!

EDIT: I believe this solution should also work in portrait mode as well.  I have not tested it though.