# Screen size from Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, size, screen

I'm trying to get the screen size from a widget using the following code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

I suppose it should give me the screen size in pixels.

I'm trying to get sizes on a Nexus 7 tablet (1280 x 800) and on a LGE610(320 x 480);

How is it possible, that I get 482 pixels for the first one and 480 for the second one? On a Galaxy Nexus (Maguro) I get 526 instead...

Is it possible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)

> Gets the size of the display, in pixels.
>
> Note that this value should not be used for computing layouts, since a
>   device will typically have screen decoration (such as a status bar)
>   along the edges of the display that reduce the amount of application
>   space available from the size returned here. Layouts should instead
>   use the window size.
>
> The size is adjusted based on the current rotation of the display.
>
> The size returned by this method does not necessarily represent the
>   actual raw size (native resolution) of the display. The returned size
>   may be adjusted to exclude certain system decoration elements that are
>   always visible. It may also be scaled to provide compatibility with
>   older applications that were originally designed for smaller displays.

In other words, what you get from getSize is inconsistent depending the presence of title bars and so on.  Caveat emptor.

Here's a more thorough discussion:

[How can I get android Honeycomb system's screen width and height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144814/how-can-i-get-android-honeycomb-systems-screen-width-and-height)

Answer (score -1):

You can get widget size in dp, but i don`t how get resized widget hight and width.

```
public class MyProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
 @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        for (int i : appWidgetIds) {
            updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, i);
            AppWidgetProviderInfo info = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(i);
            int highResize = info.minResizeHeight;
            int weighResize = info.minResizeWidth;
            int high = info.minHeight;
            int weigh = info.minWidth;
        }
    }
}
```