# How can I get the width and Height of the screen -Android

Tags: java, android

I tried using

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

metrics.heightPixels;
metrics.widthPixels;
```

but because I use  `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY` the width is no right.
It shows the size without the navigation bar. but I want to know all the screen size..

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is only possible in API 17 and later. Just use [`getRealMetrics(metrics)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealMetrics(android.util.DisplayMetrics)) instead of calling `getMetrics()`. (Or you can call [`getRealSize(Point)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRealSize(android.graphics.Point)) if all you need is the size.) For an approach to use with earlier API levels, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8935091/535871).

Answer (score 2):

Its working fine for me

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
int height = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Comment: my problem that I get the screen size-navigationbar size

Comment: so what u want @Alon 
?

Comment: @AndoMasahashi - OP was pretty clear: the screen size without any adjustment for decor or scaling factor.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code this is implemented in API 13

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

or

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```